# c++ Best Way to access properties of a vector element

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures

So this is a question more so for my own knowledge.
Is there any kind of best practice for accessing multiple properties of a single element in a vector? Sorry if that question doesn't make much sense. Let me give a scenario:

I was working on some code and got to a point where I created a vector of a struct. To make sure we aren't duplicating the data in the vector, we check multiple pieces of the incoming data against already existing data in the vector via a for loop. The data is being added from multiple, independent sources, sometimes at rapid succession, so it's a bit difficult to do a master ID for each entry before this point. The code ends up looking something like this:

```
    vector<testStruct> test;
    void addDataToVector(int _iData1, string _sData2, unsigned int _uiData3){
       testStruct tmp;
       tmp.iData1 = _iData1;
       tmp.sData2 = _sData2;
       tmp.uiData3 = _uiData3;

       if(test.size() > 0){
            for(size_t i = 0;; i < test.size(); i++){
                 if(test[i].iData1 == tmp.iData1 &&
                      test[i].sData2 == tmp.sData2 &&
                      test[i].uiData3 == tmp.uiData3){
                      break;
                 }else{
                      test.push_back(tmp);
                 }
             }
        }else{
             test.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }
```

In some other programming languages, I have learned that doing multiple calls on the same element of an array like this is a bit wasteful. In Action Script 3, I have learned that it is better to assign the element's content to a temporary variable then use that variable for the multiple calls instead of constantly accessing the vector over and over.
I am wondering if there is any such thing to be wary of in c++? I understand that a vector is a pointer... I think. But I'm not sure if that alleviates a lot of this or if I need to still be on the look out for such a thing. I have tried looking around for similar data/answers but wasn't exactly sure how to word my search.

Any help or pointers (hehe get it?) would be appreciated.

Comment: Is order of elements in vector important?

Comment: _"I understand that a vector is a pointer..."_ Huh??

Comment: This sounds like premature optimization. It depends on a lot of things. My advice is: Don't bother trying to optimize the code by trying to introduce new temporary variables; the compiler usually does a better job than you.

Comment: @Pavel:Edit: Not they aren't important.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Am I wrong in that? Is a vector not a pointer of sorts?

Comment: @TorkelBjørnson-Langen: Oh ok. The code base for this is pretty old (written in visual studio 2003) and we can't move out of it right now so I try to optimize where I can. I do thank you for that advice though and will take it to heart.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, VS2013 implementation of `operator[]` in `vector` is exactly `return (*(this->_Myfirst + _Pos));`, so in this sense `vector` *is* sort of a pointer, just like an array is. Not in a strict sense, though.

Comment: If you're concerned about efficiency, and your vector isn't going to store duplicates, a `std::set<testStruct>` would be may more efficient than all of that code you wrote, especially if there are going to be a lot of `testStruct` objects.

Comment: @Maxxumas It's considered a _wrapped pointer_ at best. `std::vector` is a **template class**.

Comment: *To make sure we aren't duplicating the data in the vector, we check multiple pieces of the incoming data against already existing data in the vector via a for loop* -- Time to consider using a `std::set`.   For example [here is an implementation using std::set](http://ideone.com/mvmxMx).  What if you have 10,000 items, and it's the last one that matches the one you're trying to insert?  Using a vector, you have to loop through the entire sequence.  Not so with a `std::set`, as it uses a tree-like structure, thus using a binary search to find the insertion point.

Comment: Thanks everyone for telling me about sets. I had never even heard of them before now. Reminds me of a link list slightly. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only a vector is a pointer (sort of, more like a wrapper around an array), but it's also a template, meaning that its whole implementation is typically accessible to the compiler at the time you use it. Meaning that the compiler *knows* exactly what `test[i]` is, and may optimize away this stuff for you. You need not to concern yourself with such things. Element access is *very* fast for vectors.

You may wish to overload `operator==` for your structure, though, so you can write `test[i] == tmp` instead. That will improve readability for your code, but you should only do that if that fields being equal actually means the objects are being equal, that is, if that makes sense *semantically*.

Or, if at some point you just wish to access an element just once for some other reason rather than performance (say, the access expression is too long to repeat comfortably), you can easily do this:

```
const testStruct &element = test[i];
```

Note the `&`—you avoid the unnecessary cost of copying this way, and access the vector element directly. Remove `const` if you need to modify the element.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sergey. I appreciate the well explained answer. I also appreciate the suggestions. Helps me learn new things. You rock!

Answer (score 1):

When the order is not important, it's better to use `set` instead of `vector`. Set is used to store a group of unique items. When your add an item to a set, computer will check if it already presents. If no, the item will be added to the set. It will work faster, namely one adding will take O(log N) instead of O(N) time.

*Also it allows you to check if an element presents in a set or to delete an element by O(log N) time.*

Function will look like this:

```
set<testStruct> test;
void add(int _iData1, string _sData2, unsigned int _uiData3) {
    testStruct tmp;
    tmp.iData1 = _iData1;
    tmp.sData2 = _sData2;
    tmp.uiData3 = _uiData3;
    test.insert(tmp);
}
```

Or you'll be able to write just

```
test.emplace(i, s, ui);
```

to insert the item whithout any additional functions.

Comment: I've never even heard of a Set before. I'll look it up though for my own knowledge. The code that this is being written for is old. Visual Studio 2003 c++ old. It can't be moved out of that as it's basically the core of how our company operates. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really necessary to copy the data in the first lines of the function to the test struct? I would compare the passed parameters directly with the array-values and construct the struct only before pushing back.

You seem not to use constructors - why?

And to your question about the rapidly incoming data streams - describe the topology of the whole system, please. Maybe a central queue-component or something like this may help?

Comment: It's an old server built for casino gaming. It was built in Visual Studio's 2003 with c++ and is fairly huge... and confusing. It's a work thing that I got thrown into and had to learn c++ for so I always feel like my knowledge is crappy compared to what it should be. Multiple client machines connect to it and send hundreds of requests for everything from game data to payouts, updates, ect. So I want to try and keep things moving as fast and clean as possible. That's why I was curious if the way I was coding this part was optimal.

Answer (score -3):

Does `testStruct` contain only fields `iData1`, `sData2` and `uiData3`? If yes, you can simple compare objects like `test[i] == tmp`.

Besides if the order of elements is not important, you can solve your problem easier and at the same time more effectively. In this case use `set` instead of `vector`.